# What is the difference between com.sun.lwuit.Form.show() and com.sun.lwuit.Form.showBack()?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, mobile-application, midp-2.0, lwuit-form

What is the difference between `com.sun.lwuit.Form.show()` and `com.sun.lwuit.Form.showBack()`? I think both are displays the form. I think both are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose form.Show() the form will slide in from the right side of the display and move to the left (By default.)

If you choose form.showBack()the form will slide in from the LEFT side of the display and move to the RIGHT(By default.)

You can reverse the direction of transition too.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Form.html#show%28%29) and [here](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Form.html#showBack%28%29) you can see the difference. showBack is also showing the form, but it reverses the direction of the transition.

Comment: Lajos Arpad-I cannot understand the phrase -"it reverses the direction of the transition." so please give more details.Dont mistake me.

Comment: If you don't understand transitions, please read this: http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/animations/Transition.html it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal use I use `Form.show()` to show new Form and the `Form.showback()` is used to show previous shown form with data filled by user as cache.

Comment: How does this answer the question about the *technical differences* between the two? You're just stating your personal preference here.